# how to fix my laravel heroku deployment error

Tags: laravel, heroku, composer-php

I am trying to install my laravel app to Heroku and I am getting an error for dependency installation

I have tried  composer update and composer install on my local machine before redeploying

the error I got from pushing to Heroku

```
remote:        Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: An error occurred during a database connection or query
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !     
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - An error occurred during a database connection or query
remote:
```

The composer.jso file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.2",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "v2.0.0-alpha8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

I want the laravel code to successfully deploy and build on Heroku server

Comment: I had a similar issue when using tcg/voyager because it uses database based config and fails to connect when initializing

Comment: so how did you go about it Caddy DZ i really need to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who face this problem, please delete your `composer.lock` file and reinstall `composer install`